# How do i get rid of bountys?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got a 20k bounty and every guard and jarl just try to kill me so I cant speak to them to go to prison or pay it off

Comment: It is indeed similar, although leo is asking specifically about how remove the bounty once all of the NPC's are hostile toward you and won't initiate dialog.

Comment: @Guy That's handled in the other question as well.

Comment: Oh you're right, that's true. They don't cover all the methods, but I did miss that it covers it at the end.

Comment: Just kill every gard of the game ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**You can either be promoted to the rank of Thane by a Jarl**, which provides a one-time clear of all bounties in the Hold where you got promoted, or **pay the bounty to the guards.**

Comment: But what if the player is not a Thane? Besides, if he/she isn't, it would probably be too late to do that. Besides, he wants to get to the arrest dialogue.

Comment: Being promoted to Thane clears every bounty in the Hold **only once**. @JimJones

Answer (score 0):

Usually the guards should stop attacking you once you have sheathed your weapon. However if that does not work you may have to just go through your saves till you find one where you have a lower bounty or no bounty at all. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bounty), you can get the guards to initiate their dialogue again by:

- Sheathing your weapon in front of them (if it is already sheathed, then take it out and sheath it again. Try this a few times to make sure they're actually not accepting your surrender.)

And/or if that doesn't work, try

- Leaving and letting a few days of in-game time to pass. When you come back into the offended city a few days later, the guards should attempt to talk to you first again.